# how to install R libraries on remote server?

Tags: r

I have to use a remoter server to run some R code, but I am getting errors when trying to install the libraries. I have the install.packages() and library() functions for each package, but keep getting this error.

Libraries

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("miccec/yaGST") 
library(yaGST)
install_github("AntonioDeFalco/SCEVAN")
library(SCEVAN)
install.packages("seurat")
library(Seurat)
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
```

Error Message

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("devtools") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("devtools") : unable to install packages
Execution halted
```

Is there a better way to add R libraries to a remote server?

Comment: You'll have to use a different directory like Ben mentioned. You don't have permission to write to the directory you are attempting to write to.

Answer (score 1):

Install the packages to a local library for which you have write access, e.g.

```r
dir_create("R_libs")
.libPaths(new = "R_libs")
install.packages(..., lib = "R_libs")
```

You'll need to add "R_libs" (or whatever) to your R library path in each R session, either by calling `.libPaths(new = "R_libs")` or by setting the `R_LIBS_USER` shell variable (see `?.libPaths`)

Comment: Any idea why R isn't suggesting to install into a personal directory? Isn't that the default behavior when it can't write to the default path? Is that something the server admin would have had to disable?

Comment: don't know - first guess would be that the OP is running R in non-interactive mode (wouldn't be a surprising way to be running code on a remote server)